# How can I Open all CSV files in a folder, Run text to columns, then Save as new file?

Tags: vba, excel, csv, delimiter

I've to sort up a macro to read all CSV's in a folder, apply Delimiters and then save as a new file.
Currently I can get it to open all CSV's in a folder and save them as new Workbooks, but applying the Text to Column in the middle of that process is proving tricky.

```
Sub CSVtoXLS()
Dim xFd As FileDialog
Dim xSPath As String
Dim xCSVFile As String
Dim xWsheet As String
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.StatusBar = True
xWsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
xFd.Title = "Select a folder:"
If xFd.Show = -1 Then
    xSPath = xFd.SelectedItems(1)
Else
    Exit Sub
End If
If Right(xSPath, 1) <> "\" Then xSPath = xSPath + "\"
xCSVFile = Dir(xSPath & "*.csv")
Do While xCSVFile <> ""
    Application.StatusBar = "Converting: " & xCSVFile
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=xSPath & xCSVFile
    
    Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
    :="|", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, _
    1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12 _
    , 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), _
    Array(19, 1), Array(20, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(22, 1), Array(23, 1), Array(24, 1), Array( _
    25, 1), Array(26, 1), Array(27, 1), Array(28, 1), Array(29, 1), Array(30, 1), Array(31, 1), _
    Array(32, 1), Array(33, 1), Array(34, 1), Array(35, 1), Array(36, 1), Array(37, 1), Array( _
    38, 1), Array(39, 1), Array(40, 1), Array(41, 1), Array(42, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers _
    :=True
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Windows(xWsheet).Activate
    xCSVFile = Dir
Loop
Application.StatusBar = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The key point here is how to "apply delimiters", so can you explain exactly what you mean by that for your case? For example, are tab delimiters present and you want to replace them all by commas? If so, is it simply a matter of replacing all tabs in each file with commas? etc..

Comment: The Format of the  CSVS is as follows 
EMPLOYEE NUMBER|POST ID|DATE COMMENCED POST|DATE COMMENCED POSTPS|DATE CEASED  
So I'd need to separate where the "|" are

All text is currently in Cell A1 and I need to split it all in to the relevant Cells so A1, B1, C1 and so on down the Rows.

Comment: so does that mean it's simply a matter of replacing all | with some other character? If so, there are many programs which do batch find-and-replace across multiple files such as notepad++, brackets, etc...

Comment: It would be a case of having breaking out everything before each | and placing it in cell.

So for example if it was A|B|C|D|E then A would be in A1, B Would be in B1 C would be in C1 and so on. 
I've been asked to do this via a macro in Excel.  I thought text to columns would be the simplest way to do this?

Comment: It sounds like you're describing something which Excel's import wizard does. Data-->Get Data-->From File-->From Text/csv.  Have you tried that?

Comment: I'm basically trying to do that functionality to automatically happen on every CSV file in a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below after placing the csv files in the same directory with the workbook.

```
Option Explicit
Dim theDir As String, wk As Workbook, numFiles As Integer, s As String, r As Range
Const ext = ".csv"

Sub csvToXLSX()
  theDir = ThisWorkbook.Path
  s = Dir(theDir & "\*" & ext)
  While s <> ""
    Set wk = Workbooks.Open(theDir & "\" & s)
    Set r = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown))
    r.TextToColumns Destination:=r, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:= _
    "|", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1)) _
    , TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wk.SaveAs Filename:=theDir & "\" & s & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    wk.Close False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    s = Dir()
    numFiles = numFiles + 1
  Wend
  MsgBox (numFiles & " files were processed.")
End Sub
```